# Question about the tail of a random variable

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am doing Kolmogorov's zero-one law and I am stuck here:

> Let $(\Omega, S, P)$ be a probability space and $X_1, X_2,.....$ be a sequence of the random variables on a probability space then the sigma-algebra $T=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\sigma(X_n,X_{n+1.....)}$ is called the tail of the sigma-algebra. Let $T_n=\sigma(X_n,X_{n+1},....)$ and $f_n=\sigma(X_1,X_2,.....X_n)$  then $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n$ is an algebra that generates $T_1$.

I have no idea how they have written this line, if anyone can explain it with some hint or anyhow that will be a great help. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a mistake in the definition of $f_n$? it does not depend on $n$

Comment: Yes,Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: Hint: observe that the sequence of $\sigma$-algebras $f_n$ is increasing. Therefore, for every finite collection of sets $A_1,...,A_m$ in $\bigcup f_n$ there  will be a $n_0$ such that those sets all belong to $f_{n_0}.$ Now check the properties of a [set algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_sets#Definitions).